# Connecting HTML and database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm trying to store the values in the HTML page into the database I have created, the databse has 6 columns for each slider. The columns are: value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, and value6. Also, I want to connect the database with PHP. The buttons in the HTML page does nothing, and I couldn't figure out how to make them functional.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>

  <head>

  <style>
        h1 {text-align: center;}

    </style>
    
        <title>Multiple sliders</title>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
        
        <!-- Heading -->
        <h1>  Multiple sliders </h1>
        
        <form action = "details_entry.php" method="POST">
        
    
  <div class="slidecontainer">

    <input type="range" min="0" max="360" value="180" class="slider" id="myRange">
    <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p> <label> Slider 1</label>
  </div>

  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="360" value="180" class="slider" id="myRange2">
     <p>Value: <span id="demo2"></span></p> <label> Slider 2</label>
  </div>

  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="360" value="180" class="slider" id="myRange3">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo3"></span></p>  <label> Slider 3</label> 
  </div>

  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="360" value="180" class="slider" id="myRange4">
    <p>Value: <span id="demo4"></span></p> <label> Slider 4</label>
  </div>

  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="360" value="180" class="slider" id="myRange5">
    <p>Value: <span id="demo5"></span></p> <label>Slider 5</label>
  </div>

  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="360" value="180" class="slider" id="myRange6">
    <p>Value: <span id="demo6"></span></p> <label> Slider 6</label>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
      <button class="button" >Save</button>
  </div>

  <div class="button10" > 
   <button class="button1" >On/Off</button>
  </div>





  <script>
  var slider1 = document.getElementById("myRange");
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
  demo.innerHTML = slider1.value;

  slider1.oninput = function() {
    demo.innerHTML = this.value;
  }
  </script>

  <script>
  var slider2 = document.getElementById("myRange2");
  var output = document.getElementById("demo2");
  output.innerHTML = slider2.value;

  slider2.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
  }
  </script>

  <script>
  var slider3 = document.getElementById("myRange3");
  var output3 = document.getElementById("demo3");
  output3.innerHTML = slider3.value;
  
  slider3.oninput = function() {
    output3.innerHTML = this.value;
  }
  </script>


  <script>
  var slider4 = document.getElementById("myRange4");
  var demo4 = document.getElementById("demo4");
  demo4.innerHTML = slider4.value;

  slider4.oninput = function() {
    demo4.innerHTML = this.value;
  }
  </script>

  <script>
  var slider5 = document.getElementById("myRange5");
  var output5 = document.getElementById("demo5");
  output5.innerHTML = slider5.value;

  slider5.oninput = function() {
    output5.innerHTML = this.value;
  }
  </script>

  <script>
  var slider6 = document.getElementById("myRange6");
  var output6 = document.getElementById("demo6");
  output6.innerHTML = slider6.value;

  slider6.oninput = function() {
    output6.innerHTML = this.value;
  }
  </script>


  </body>
  </html>
```

CSS

```
   * {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
   }
   body {
     height: 100vh;
     background-color: #000;
     font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
     background: linear-gradient(180deg, #db302a 0%, #62186b 100%) no-repeat;
   }



   .slidecontainer {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
   }


   .slider {
     margin-top: 4vh;
     /*moves the slider up or below */
   }

   label{
       text-align: right;
       text-indent: 250px;
       text-align-last: right;
       line-height: -200px;
       margin-top: -17px;
       margin-left: -10px;
       font-size: 20px;
   }


   .wrapper {
       text-align: center;
   }

   .button {
       position: absolute;
       top: 60%;
       left:52%;
       font-size: 20px;
   }

   .button10 {
       text-align: center;
   }

   .button1 {
       position: absolute;
       top: 60%;
       left:47%;
       font-size: 20px;
   }
```

PHP

```
   <?php
   $username='root';
   $password= '';
   $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','robot_arm_values');
   if($conn->connect_error){
       die('connection Failed:'.$conn->connection_error);


   }
       else{
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into robot_arm_values(value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6)                       values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("iiiiii",$value1,$value2,$value3,$value4,$value5,$value6);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "Values have been modified successfully!";
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
}
   ?>
```

Comment: "_The buttons in the HTML page does nothing_" In the given context the code seems to work as it is. Check the console for errors, and see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/1169519

Comment: You need to send the value through either GET or POST method... and the way you are sending data is not quite right...its better if you look up some form handling tutorials in php first ....

Comment: You also haven't closed your form tag, that won't be helping. Always double-check your work carefully. The rest, is the kind of thing you can learn from PHP forms tutorials.

Comment: Break it down into pieces and make sure each piece works?